# Backbone saving model on server

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to backbone. I am trying to save model on server but it gives me

error :

```
[HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 1010ms]
```

Where i am lacking?

My code is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >

    var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'http://192.168.1.3:8080/app/profile/astro'
    });

    var user=new UserModel();
    console.log('here ');
    user.toJSON();
    user.save({
    'dob':'89 jan'

    },{
    wait:true,
    success:function(model, response) {
    console.log('Successfully saved!');
    },
    error: function(model, error) {
    console.log(model.toJSON());
    console.log('error.responseText');
    console.log(error);
    }
    }); 
    </script>



 Server code is:

@POST
@Path("/astro")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addAstro(Astro astro)
{
ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
try
{
profileBusinessServiceImpl.saveAstro(astro, "52f5c59884aedfe7e051fd38");

builder.status(Status.OK);
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
return builder.build();
}
```

I have tested my service with postman . And  its working.

Comment: You send cross domain request?

Comment: @FUserThrowError Its on different server

Comment: You can see to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: @FUserThrowError From same server i can fetch data but can not post

Comment: can you provide server code?

Comment: @FUserThrowError i edit my question with server code